# Windows server 2008 SP2 Event Viewer "last 30 days" incorrect filter

Tags: windows-server-2008, logging

I've encountered this problem in my server - Windows server 2008 SP2.
Whenever I try to filter the log with option - "last 30 days". I got the result which was more than 30 days from today.

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you reading the dates correctly? That is, the system locale is set to US style dates and you live in the UK.

Comment: Also make sure your system time is correct.

Comment: I checked the Regional settings, everything is default - US standard.The time is correct. Also when I saved the filtered log, the information is usually less than the result I saw in the Event Viewer.